# When does Modernizr load the script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

I have implemented this code:

```
<script>
       var mod_PPfix = false;

        Modernizr.load({
            test: Modernizr.csstransitions && Modernizr.input.required,
            nope: ['script1.js', 'script2.js'],
            complete: function () {

                mod_PPfix = true;
                console.log('ppfix');
            }
        });
</script>
```

few lines after, I've placed this other script

```
<script>               
   if (!mod_PPfix) {
       $(document).ready(function() { 

           console.log('this should be seen only if modernizr's tests are true');
       });
   }
</script>
```

Now I'm really a rookie with javascript, but I expected from the code above to show the second `console.log()` only if the modernizr tests result to be true. Still the second log is recorded even when the tests result negative.

As far as I can tell, in the console the second `console.log()` message appears before the first one saying 'ppfix' so I guess that it should be a sort of load timing issue, but I really don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

If it can help I'm using Jquery as library.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the the second log message when the tests are true, don't you mean `if (mod_PPfix)`? Your version will log output the second message if the tests failed (see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaXRm/))

When you use Modernizr.load things happen asynchronously so the second `<script>` might run before script1.js and script2.js finish loading and therefore before the `complete` callback fires. Whatever you want to do in the second `<script>` you should call in the `complete` callback. For example

```
    Modernizr.load({
        test: Modernizr.csstransitions && Modernizr.input.required,
        nope: ['script1.js', 'script2.js'],
        complete: function () {
            initialize_me();
        }
    });
```

Where the `initialize_me()` function would be defined elsewhere and might have have code that looks like

```
if (Modernizr.csstransitions && Modernizr.input.required) {
    // Use CSS3
} else {
    // Do things that depended on script1.js and script2.js being loaded
}
```

Comment: **don't you mean if (mod_PPfix)?** I'm sorry it's a bit tortuous i know, what I meant is "if modernizr verify that BOTH those feats are NOT implemented then it will load the 2 scripts i listed and set to mod_PPfix = true". Again ONLY IF BOTH ARE NOT supported, load the scripts and execute the complete function. 

If the features result supported then he will do nothing, no scripts loading and no complete function will be executed. 

Is the code i posted correct with what i meant?

Comment: _Whatever you want to do in the second <script> you should call in the complete callback._        I'm really a novice, what you mean exactly with this?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Ok, now I understand better. Actually the `complete` clause runs whether the tests pass or fail -- either way they are complete. I edited my answer with an example of calling an init function from `complete`.

Comment: Now it make sense. Knowing what `complete` does now I can go on with what I need. The code and question I asked are just wrong for what I need, still your input helped me getting out of this, so i'm accepting your answer in any case. Thanks a lot, cheers! ;)